# How to create a weave cluster to migrate traffic to another weave instance when one weave instance fails?

Tags: deployment, cluster-computing

My goal: How to deploy instances of weave in a distributed manner to quickly migrate traffic to another weave instance in the event of weave failure

As mentioned in the document, the backup mechanism can be implemented through "Replication" by enabling it in the schema

{"class": "ExampleClass", "properties": [{"name": "exampleProperty", "dataType": ["text"]}], "replicationConfig": {"factor": 3 # Integer, default 1 How many copies of this class will be stored

Is data synchronization between multiple weave instances enabled by default after using replicationConfig configuration? Where does it need to be configured?

Is it configured through Kubernetes?